# Javascript multiple of the same object within an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I need to edit a property of an object in javascript. It contains multiple of the same object name. I am fairly familiar with javascript. My object looks like this:

```
var object = {
Sub: {
name: "FirstSubName",
propertyToChange: "Keep me the same"
},
Sub: {
name: "SecondSubName",
propertyToChange: "Change me" //This is the property I need to change
}
}
```

I want to change the second property of the second "Sub" to "ChangedProperty". If I want to do it without using chronological order (like `object.Sub[1].propertyToChange = "ChangedProperty"`, what would I do?

Comment: You cannot have two properties with the same name. If you start with that object, the first value is dropped and not recoverable. Fix whatever generated this object literal.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi said, you cannot have these two properties. What you can have is an array, like this:

```
    var object = {
        Sub:[{name: "X", prop: "a property"},{name: "Y", prop: "another prop"}]
    }
```

So, you can access them with the array notation you used in your question or either using a forEach for comparing values, for instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! What if I were to put brackets on the outside to make it an array of objects?

Comment: If I understood correctly, yes. This is JS notation of an array and array is a JSON valid value.

This should enlight your path:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp